# If $a^2$ is divisible by $\frac{(p+1)c^2}{pd^2}$, is $a$ also divisible by $\frac{(p+1)c^2}{pd^2}$ and why?

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading the proof that between any two real number, there exists an irrational number. To do this, they first try to show that $\sqrt{\frac{(p+1)c^2}{pd^2}}$ is irrational.

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ be integers. Then

$$
a^2=\frac{(p+1)c^2}{pd^2}b^2
$$
shows that $a^2$ is divisble by $\frac{(p+1)c^2}{pd^2}$.

**Question:** Is $a$ also divisible by $\frac{(p+1)c^2}{pd^2}$ and why?

### Edit

Here is the structure of the proof.

1. Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers and $x<y$. Show that there are rational numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $x<a<b<y$.
2. Let $a=c/e$ and $b=d/e$, where $c$, $d$, and $e$ are integers. Show that there is a prime number $p$ such that $\frac{p+1}{p}<\frac{d^2}{c^2}$.
3. Show that $\frac{c^2}{e^2}<\frac{(p+1)c^2}{pe^2}<\frac{d^2}{e^2}$.
4. Show that $\sqrt{\frac{(p+1)c^2}{pe^2}}$ is irrational.
5. Prove that between any two real number, there exists an irrational number.

Comment: The answer to the title question is negative. For example, $a^2$ is divisible by $a^2$ but $a$ is (generally) not.

Comment: I have edited the question. I did not mean any number but $\frac{(p+1)c^2}{pd^2}$!

Comment: That's missing context and details, such as what are $a,b,p,c,d$ and what are the other assumptions.

Comment: $\frac{(p+1)c^2}{pb^2}$ is not integer, in general (because $p\nmid (p+1)$). However, that's not what you're asked to prove.

Comment: Please see my edit. I am following the proof of irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ to prove the irrationality of $\sqrt{\frac{(p+1)c^2}{pe^2}}$. That is arguing by contradiction that $\sqrt{\frac{(p+1)c^2}{pe^2}}$ is rational.

Comment: @AnonymousStudent You can't follow the proof that closely, unfortunately - what you're trying to do doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying too hard to make this proof look like the one for $\sqrt{2}$; they *don't* quite go the same way, although at the end we do wind up recapitulating that argument.

First, to your original question: there is no reason for it to be (and as G. Sassatelli's comment states, ${(p+1)c^2\over pd^2}$ need not be an integer in the first place!) and it is unnecessary for the proof that it be.

Now, onto the actual proof. Supposing there were such $a, b$ (for a given, $p, c, d$), by rearranging the equation we get ${p\over p+1}={b^2c^2\over a^2d^2}$; taking the square root of both sides then gives $$\sqrt{p\over p+1}={bc\over ad}.$$ It will now be enough to show that the left hand side is irrational; this will yield a contradiction since the right hand side clearly *is* rational.

It is **here** that we follow the picture set by the $\sqrt{2}$ argument! Suppose $\sqrt{p\over p+1}={m\over n}$ for coprime integers $m, n$; squaring and rearranging gives $pn^2=(p+1)m^2$. Do you see how to go from here?

Comment: Please see the edit in my question.

Comment: @AnonymousStudent I'm not sure how that edit affects anything (other than changing a "$d$" to an "$e$"). It is still the case that the relevant fraction need not be an integer, so divisibility by it doesn't make sense, and that you don't need divisibility in the first place as I've outlined.

Comment: @AnonymousStudent See my edit. You're trying to make the proof follow the lines of the $\sqrt{2}$ case too closely, and that's not going to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see what I have been doing wrong. I feel stupid!